# Argument calculated every time to be passed in multiple listeners

Tags: java, performance, jvm

For the following code:

```
public void execute(Object[] arguments)
{
  for(MyListener listener : listOfListeners)
  {
    listener.apply(((Double) arguments[0]).longValue());
  }
}
```

Will the longValue() be called for all the listeners or will JVM optimize this and will calculate only once? In other words: Is the above slower than this:

```
public void execute(Object[] arguments)
{
  long id = ((Double) arguments[0]).longValue()
  for(MyListener listener : listOfListeners)
  {
    listener.apply(id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this optimization is called [loop invariant hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion), and HotSpot JVM definitely [can do this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#server).

We can verify this with a simple [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark.

```
package bench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class Listeners {
    List<Listener> listOfListeners = IntStream.range(0, 50)
            .mapToObj(Listener::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Object[] arguments = {Math.random()};

    @Benchmark
    public void inside() {
        for (Listener listener : listOfListeners) {
            listener.apply(((Double) arguments[0]).longValue());
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void outside() {
        long id = ((Double) arguments[0]).longValue();
        for (Listener listener : listOfListeners) {
            listener.apply(id);
        }
    }

    static class Listener {
        private long sum;

        Listener(int initialValue) {
            this.sum = initialValue;
        }

        public void apply(long id) {
            sum += id;
        }
    }
}
```

The results show that both `inside` and `outside` methods are equal in terms of performance.

```
Benchmark          Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
Listeners.inside   avgt   10  53,354 ± 0,317  ns/op
Listeners.outside  avgt   10  53,690 ± 0,373  ns/op
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)